# When can a matrix with negative entries have a completely non-negative dominant eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Perron-Forbenius obviously answers this question for positive and for certain non-negative matrices. I want to know whether these conditions can be weakened at all. In other words, what, if anything, can be said about the class of matrices which have some negative entries but still have non-negative dominant eigenvectors. Is this even possible? I haven't been able to construct an example although I haven't tried particularly hard so far.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: http://www.math.drexel.edu/~abed/ELAvol17_pp389-413.pdf

This somewhat answers the question if anyone is curious, although not completely, so if you have more information to add please feel free!